# What do I need to take care of when releasing an OSX Electron build?

Tags: macos, electron

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere - I couldn't find it.

Being the developer of a web application (PWA), I'd like to offer an Electron build for **Mac users** since Safari does not support some advanced features like Service Workers, yet.

I'm not very familiar with Mac peculiarities (I'm rather a Linux & Windows user), so I'm not sure what I need to take care of when releasing a downloadable program. I'm not so interested in the App store (which needs some [additional steps](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide/))  - I guess it would be enough if my users could simply download an installation package, like the Chrome team seems to do for it's browser.

Do such packages need to be signed in some way or can I simply create an MacOS-Electron-Build and publish the resulting binary on my website, assuming that Mac users will know how to install it?

Comment: if you supply the bundled package onto your website, how would your users know to trust the package? (hence why it's useful to publish on the app store). Natively, the OS will not install an unsigned app (user has to change security settings); Secondly, you are possibly exposing the application to be copied (since it's easy to view the sourcecode `no compilation to binary`)

Comment: Okay, so every application should be signed. Which involves fees to pay to Apple. I guess this answers my question, thanks.

Comment: I mean you don't necessarily have to sign it; (such as `mojibar` - i don't think that's signed, but you trust it since it's on github and you can view the sourcecode)

Comment: But, if I understand you correctly, an unsigned package won't install unless the user changes the security settings (just like Android). That's a no-go for me, so apparently there aren't many options for me...

Comment: yes exactly; (to get a developer certificate, you'd need to pay apple for a developer account `$99` and maybe any other fees); much like in Microsoft VS. I'll add a proper answer later;

Answer (score 0):

So to get a user to install an electron application, you have a couple options.

Firstly, due to Apples default security settings, most unsigned applications will require the user to verify and allow the unsigned application to be installed. (So basically an extra step for the user... not entirely great for non savvy users)

To expand from this, to get a developer certificate, you'll need to get one from Apple (as to verify the authenticity of the application to your users)

As a precursor, I don't think it's entirely related to putting the app on the App Store, however you do need to have pay Apple $99 for a Mac developer account. (Not the iOS account).

This mirrors the process if you were to develop on Microsoft systems which require you to have a developer certificate via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a pwa deployed and running at https://myawesome.pwa
Just use https://github.com/vladikoff/PWAify

```
npm i -g pwaify
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 pwaify https://myawesome.pwa --platforms=darwin
```

- Icons are a manual process. Check docs.
- You might not need the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 but would not work for me otherwise.